# Error Updating AWS Elasticsearch Settings Via Command Line

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to update the settings of an AWS Elasticsearch instance. My command is :

`curl -XPUT "https://<index-endpoint>.es.amazonaws.com/_settings" -d @/path/to/settings.json`

And I receive the following response:

```
{
    "Message":"Your request: '/_settings' is not allowed."
}
```

I've read that not all ES commands are not accepted by an AWS instance of ES, but I can't find an alternative for what I'm doing.

---

Note:

My settings are as follows:

```
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "urls-links-emails": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to apply those settings to a specific index, so your endpoint needs to be something like `https://<index-endpoint>.es.amazonaws.com/myindex/_settings`

Comment: I think you need to use `--data-binary` instead of `-d`. Documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Comment: @Val Thanks, your answer was what allowed us update the settings. Feel free to submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think you only need to worry about using `--data-binary` for bulk requests. This is because it uses newline delimited JSON. The settings request is regular json where newlines don't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply those settings to a specific index, so your endpoint needs to be something like `https://<index-endpoint>.es.amazonaws.com/myindex/_settings`

More concretely, your command needs to be like this:

```
curl -XPUT https://<index-endpoint>.es.amazonaws.com/myindex/_settings --data-binary @/path/to/settings.json
```